# RequiredFieldValidator not allowing Chinese characters

Tags: asp.net, utf-8, requiredfieldvalidator, chinese-locale

I have a standard RequiredFieldValidator on an ASP.NET 4.0 web form. It behaves fine for English names, but for some reason it won't validate if I use Chinese characters. I already tried changing the encoding meta tag from this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

to this with no effect:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I also verified the globalization settings are default, meaning the request/response are utf-8 as well.

Is this a known issue with ASP.NET, and is there a workaround?

Here is the test data I'm using:

```
Last Name: 方
First Name: 李
Address1: 香港东路6号
Address2: 5号楼,8号室
City: 青岛市
State: 山东
```

Comment: Does "won't validate" refer to server-side or client-side validation, or both? (I just checked in a ASP.Net 3.5 application, and it validates your test data)

Comment: It is a validator control on the ascx, but there is also a server side call to rfv.IsValid that's returning false. Why would the code-behind behavior differ?

Comment: It turns out one of my developers had an event handler which was stripping out non-ASCII on postback. Issue resolved :)